# Structure C: Storing values in an array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, structure

Can anyone advise why values are not getting stored in struct array? 
I tried to store values in buffer array and I notice values that are getting stored 0 or 1 not user input.

This is what I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int menu(void);
struct item
{
    int i_SKU;
    int i_QUANTITY;
    int i_PRICE;
};

int main()
{
    int i,j = 0;;
    int n;
    int input;
    //struct item item1[10] = { {0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0} };
    struct item item1[]={0};
    struct item buff[]={0};
    //printf("size of %d", sizeof(item1)/sizeof(item1[0]));
    printf("Welcome to the Inventory\n");
    printf("===================\n");
B: printf("Please select from the following:\n");

A: menu();
    scanf("%d", &input);

    switch (input)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("Inventory\n");
            printf("=========================================\n");
            printf("ku     Price     Quant\n");
            for (i = 0; i < sizeof(buff)/sizeof(buff[0]); i++)
            {
                printf("%d     %d        %d\n", buff[i].i_SKU, buff[i].i_PRICE, buff[i].i_QUANTITY);
            }
            printf("=========================================\n");
            goto B;

        case 2:
            //n = sizeof(item1)/sizeof(item1[0]) + 1;
            //for (i=n; i < ; i++)
            printf("Please input a KU number:");
            buff[j].i_SKU=scanf("%d", &item1[j].i_SKU);
            printf("Quantity:");
            buff[j].i_QUANTITY=scanf("%d", &item1[j].i_QUANTITY);
            printf("Price:");
            buff[j].i_PRICE=scanf("%d", &item1[j].i_PRICE);
            printf("The item added.\n");
            j=j+1;
            goto B;

        case 0:
            printf("bye!");
            exit(1);

        default:
            printf("Invalid input, try again:\n");
            goto A;
    }

    return 0;
}

int menu(void)
{
    printf("1) Display.\n");
    printf("2) Add to inventory.\n");
    printf("0) Leave.\n");
    printf("Select:");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to store values in buffer array and I notice values that are getting stored 0 or 1 not user input.

Comment: Read the [classic essay](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html) on goto statements considered harmful.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` doesn't return the value it reads, it returns the number of characters it reads.

So these lines:

```
buff[j].i_SKU=scanf("%d", &item1[j].i_SKU);
buff[j].i_SKU=scanf("%d", &item1[j].i_QUANTITY);
buff[j].i_SKU=scanf("%d", &item1[j].i_PRICE);
```

don't do what you want. They put the integer into `item1[j].i_X`, but assign `buff[j].i_X` to the number of characters read.

Also, I'm guessing you intended the left hand side of those three equations to differ, not all refer to `i_SKU`.

Another possible problem: your buffers don't have a length specified, so they will probably just have storage for one element.

**EDIT**:

I'm not sure what purpose the `items1` array serves in your code, but if you want the value in both arrays, you can try the following:

```
int sku;
printf("Please input a KU number:");
buff[j].i_SKU=scanf("%d", &sku);
item1[j].i_SKU = sku;
buff[j].i_SKU = sku;
// etc.
```

Comment: How can I store values otherwise?

Comment: The method you are using to store the values in `item1[j].i_X` should work.

Comment: Values are not getting stored in buff still

Comment: If you update your code in the question I can take a look.